# Android fragments overlap previous view and button listeners

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity A with a fragment A inside.

Activity A uses layout X, and fragment A uses layout A.

code of layout X:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="android.app.DialogFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="113dp"
    class="com.example.fragtester.FragA" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout A is just textview + linearlayout.

I set up another fragment B that uses layout B.

Now that I use the following code in activity A to change the fragments:

```
Fragment f = new FragB();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment1, f);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
ft.addToBackStack(null); 
ft.commit();
```

I end up having layout B displaying under layout A.

So I use a FrameLayout to wrap the fragment in layout X and use

```
ft.replace(R.id.FrameLayout1, f);
```

Now the view is working nicely. Though, another problem arises.

Although layout B covers layout A, but the buttons are still active.

That means when I am viewing layout B, I can still click buttons on layout A, even if I am not seeing it.

And even when I add fragment C/D/E..... (layouts C/D/E....), the buttons on layout A is still active.

Can anybody explain why is that? Am I using fragments wrongly? Thanks!

A way to get through is to make layout A blank, and use other layout to cover it. But it doesn't seems to be the "right" way??

Answer (score 3):

Remove the fragment and add a FrameLayout

```
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff" >
    </FrameLayout>
```

then add fragments programmatically.

In android fragment button click pass through the fragments (i dont know if the fragments are suppose to work like that). what I used to do in such a situation is to make the layout of the fragment clickable. so the clicks wont pass through.

Comment: may i know why is that? what's the difference between adding fragments in layout and programmatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having fragment in your xml, try to create empty container for a fragments. For example empty frame layout. And then programmatically put your fragments in there.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more why is that so? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attribute to the XML root layout of the fragment that goes on top.

```
android:clickable="true"
```

This will ensure that touch events will not propagate further than the top layer.