# Buttons interfere on overlapping fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app where one fragment is a "main menu" which can open a submenu (another fragment) based on which button is pressed.  Each submenu completely covers the main menu. When a button is pressed from the main menu, I add the transaction to the backstack like this so when the user hits the back button it will take him back to the main menu:

```
MyFragment frag = new MyFragment ();
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.main_layout, frag, "NextFrag");
transaction.addToBackStack("NextFrag");
transaction.commit();
```

I noticed that the buttons from my "main menu" fragment are still active from the second fragment even though you can't see them.  I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357721/android-fragments-overlap-previous-view-and-button-listeners) which suggested making each fragments' layout clickable

```
android:clickable="true"
```

This works but I don't understand why and feel like I'm missing something.